# C++ basic fileIO locations

Tags: c++, macos, file-io

so I'm just starting to learn `fileIO`. I've been using a program called CodeRunner on my mac and I have a folder that contains:

`validsudoku.cpp, validsudoku, sudokugood0.txt`

The beginning of the code I wrote is:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

//string filetoopen;
ifstream sudokutxtfile;
string txtline;
string sudokubox[9]; 
//bool goodsudoku = true;
//int i, j, row, column;

/*
if (argc == 2)
    filetoopen = argv[1];
else
    filetoopen = "sudokuboard.txt";
*/  

//read in file, save to array, close file
sudokutxtfile.open("sudokugood0.txt");  
while (getline(sudokutxtfile,txtline)) 
{
    sudokubox[row] = txtline;   
    row++;
}
sudokutxtfile.close();
```

Right now to test this I just have the file to open as `"sudokugood0.txt"`, although once I get this working I'll change it to my `'filetoopen'` variable so I can terminal input the file name.

**Now onto my issue:**
When I run the `.cpp` in CodeRunner it runs correctly sees the `.txt` file and processes it, but when I put the executable and the `.txt` file in my bin folder and try to run it from terminal it doesn't see the `.txt` file. Am I using the wrong location or am I missing something else?

Side question: It runs in OSX, but in my Xubuntu VMbox using Codeblocks that I'm required to use for class I get 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' Anyone know why? I have this at the top of my file for both:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Non-absolute filenames are relative to the current working directory, not the executable. If you aren't in the `bin` directory when you run the program then it won't work.

Comment: ohh, guess I should have tried that ;/  thank you. Is there any simple way to make it work from anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program tries to find the file you open in the *current* working directory, not from the location where the executable file is. When you're executing a program from a terminal the current directory is the directory you're in. So if you do e.g. `cd ~/` to go to your home-directory, and then run the program, the program will look for the file in your home-directory. If you change to some other directory, the program will look for the file in that new directory.

The natural solution is either to pass the input file as an argument to the executable, or to ask for it as input (I recommend the first).

Comment: Thank you I did what you suggested and it works in OSX now. Any idea why the same exact code doesn't work in Codeblocks on my Xubuntu VMbox? I think it might have something to do with the libraries I used, but I'm not too sure.

Comment: @AustinMW Probably because the current directory of the program is not what you think it is, with an IDE it seldom is. Often in an IDE the current directory is the project root directory, while the program is created in another sub-directory.

Comment: but instead of saying 'invalid' when it doesn't see a file it gives me the error Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: @AustinMW Then you're doing something you're not showing us. Run in a debugger to catch the crash, and ask a new question about it if you can't figure it out.